# Interface Orientation with TabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using a Tab Bar Controller in my app. In the most part of the app's behavior we have one single orientation (interfaceOrientationPortrait). But i have a view that runs a video in WebView. When i am running this video, the orientation remains portrait. I want to put for all orientations.

Well, i used the return type YES in my Video's class. Nothing has changed. I changed the return type to YES in my RootViewController class. Nothing has changed.

I would like to change the orientation only for the Video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers that are part of a tab bar controller won't rotate to an orientation if any of the tab bar controllers can not rotate to that orientation (at least if the tab bar is visible). So maybe you want to update all your controllers' method in order to let the rotation happen if the web view controller is visible on the tab bar controller.

If you need a deeper explanation, just ask. Good luck!

**Edit (example code)**

This is what could be your rotation methods for your tab bar controller view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == kMyWebViewControllerIndex))
    {
        return YES;
    } else
    {
        return (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it! 
Do you have some code for me to analyze? 
I thought about it, but i don't know how to put this on the xcode... 
(Almost new in ios development =/)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know if there is any problem!

Comment: My problem still the same ... Do you have another sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Is your web view in a view controller inside the tabBarController?

Try showing it in a modally presented view controller, it should work

Comment: Yes! But my tab bar controller has the return type portrait... i want to put the autorotate just for my video, inside the web view...

Comment: What I meant was, instead of showing your webView inside the tabBar, just present a modalController like this:

   [self presentModalViewController:controllerWithWebView animated:YES];

Comment: huuum, i'll put this line on my webView class?

Comment: not exactly, say you have your tab bar controller that swaps between a, b, and c (all view controllers), and you want to show a webView when you go into the c controller, what you do is, create a new controller that shows a web view, and put that code in the 'c' controller class, triggered by a button or something

Comment: what that will do is that you enter the 'c' controller, and shows a button or whatever you want "play video", and when you press it, a new controller is displayed ABOVE the tab bar, showing the video.
i hope this helps ...

Comment: He isn't asking how to present a view controller, just how to change the supported orientations for a specific existing controller.

Comment: Well, i created a web view inside a modalView. in my modalView class, i changed the returning type to YES (interface orientation), but still don't work...